# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb) swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I made a simple universal game in SpriteKit. I just made a new Xcode project and copy+pasted the old code from that game. All I did was delete some comments/unnecessary bits and added different images.

Everything works in the old project but in the new one, it throws an error when I'm switching to the GameOver scene. I've tried copy+pasting the new game over scene to the old project and it works fine there.

Here are the errors:

(in AppDelegate.swift)
`class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { Thread 1: SIGABRT`

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
0x1071ee278 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax
0x1071ee27d <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
0x1071ee280 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x1071ee282 <+10>: jae    0x1071ee28c               ; <+20>
    0x1071ee284 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x1071ee287 <+15>: jmp    0x1071e9ca3               ; cerror_nocancel
```

(first line in the game over scene)

```
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Lights")
Enqueued from __46-[_CUIThemePixelRendition setSharedBlockData:]_block_invoke (0)
```

I used the lights image without any problems in another scene and it still doesn't work when I take out the background so I don't think it's a problem with the image itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! :)
~Megan

Comment: Can you post the full error message?  Also, you can remove the disassembly of `__pthread_kill` since it won't help.